# Выделить  найденый текст в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, как выделить определенный текст в RichTexBox? Как, например, в обычном блокноте при поиске слова.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Windows Forms

Comment: @Air, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

А в чём проблема?

- Найти начальный индекс через [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9be0980x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Установить `SelectionStart` и `SelectionLength`